# debug native asp.net code in vstudio

Tags: asp.net, .net

Im experiencing problems with handling request, there is an error thrown in

`System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent`

How can i debug it? I dont know how to get the appropriate source code and enter that in visual studio while debugging.

Comment: Seems you need to enable .NET debugging. Here is how to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx

Comment: Try digging into it via browser dev tools (first) since it seems to be pointing to a _client_ script (that is raised at runtime).

Comment: @fly_ua Ok and then how to find this piece of code and set there breakpoint?

Comment: @gruber  - Is error in Browser or oon Server? I meant when you have issues on Server. If issue is on client side - then i was wrong with my assumption.  If on Server side - probably you may break on exception

Comment: the problem is on server so do you know how to set a breakpoint in this location, for sure it is in System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent method, I want to know why asp.net claims that there is   Invalid postback or callback argument

Comment: I would suggest you to check Debug -> Exceptions -> Break on Exception -> Thrown. and then i think this will break into debugger on error  - the same as on breakpoint, otherwise it seems you have to go step by step.

Comment: Did it but there is an information that Source Not Available :/